# "r.start is not a function" Fermipy Conda Error

Tags: python, function, statistics, jupyter, macos-catalina

I've been using the Fermipy conda environment on Python 2.7.14 64-bit on macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and overnight received the error "r.start is not a function" when trying to connect to the Jyputer server through Vscode (if I try on Jupyter Notebook/Lab the server instantly dies). I had a bunch of clutter on my system so I ended up formatting it and reinstalling all the dependencies needed (such as Conda through Homebrew, Fermitools through Conda and Fermipy through the install script on their site), but still get the same error, although I was previously running python scripts just fine. It gives me no other error or output, if it did I would attach it here. [This is the error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW02y.png)

Edit: I get the same error using any version of Python 2.7.XX and not for python 3.7.XX.

Answer (score 2):

As answered here, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12355#issuecomment-652515770

VSCode changed how it launches jupyter kernels, and the new method is incompatible with python 2.7.

Add this line to your VSCode settings.json file and restart.

```
"python.experiments.optOutFrom": ["LocalZMQKernel - experiment"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message. (r.start is not a function.)  I had an old uninstalled version of anaconda on the computer which had left behind a folder containing its python version.  Jupyter was supposed to be running from new venv after setting both python and jupyter path in vscode.  I fully deleted remaining files from old anaconda install - message went away and notebook ran fine. Maybe try getting rid of all conda stuff and pip install jupyter and anything else you need.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but I've installed Ubuntu and it works smoothly.